# I run `sudo rpi-update` have error at RPi4b

Tags: raspbian

I run sudo rpi-update, it output ↓

```
*** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: 拒绝连接
 !!! Failed to download update for rpi-update!
 !!! Make sure you have ca-certificates installed and that the time is set correctly
```

I have tried ↓

```
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

but it still the same

Comment: `rpi-update` doesn't appear to be part of the supported package management utilities in Raspberry Pi. According to their GitHub site: `Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason.`. So - you should probably direct your questions to the authors of `rpi-update`.

Comment: DO NOT run `rpi-update` unless you a) understand what it does, b) understand it can break your system, c) understand that it installs untested and experimental stuff and d) know how to recover your system in less than twenty minutes. It should not be part of your normal regular update process.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked the time of the raspberry-pi? maybe run `sudo sntp -s time.nist.gov` to be sure

Certificate Validation heavily rely on time to be correct